# Inverse/integral/limit of logarithmic function

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms

I have this problem:
$f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$,
$$f(x)=x+1+\ln x $$
$g$ is the reverse of $f$.

The problems are:

$g'(2) =$?

and

$$\int_{2}^{e+2}g(x)dx$$

and

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$$

and the solution for $$f(x) = g(x)$$
Anyone got any idea?

reverse=inverse of the function

Comment: Reverse = inverse function?

Comment: @GoodDeeds x->∞

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thansk for edit,but can you tell me how I can do those edits to not bother you? For example to convert second exercise to integral?

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thnaks but on the integral if I put $$ at end and on $ at begin but it shows at the end another $ and if in code I add any $ the code become broken

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $g$ is the inverse function of $f$, then $$g(f(x)) = x$$ for all $x \in (0,+\infty).$ Derive this expression $$g'(f(x))f'(x) =1$$ with $f'(x) = 1+\frac{1}{x}.$ Evaluate this equality at $x=1$ and you finally get $$2g'(2)=1.$$ So $$g'(2)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Beat me to it, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks dude,can you give me a clue how to get g(x) properly because I need to use it in the next 3 exercises,please?